# ANR Input dispatching timed out (server) is not responding

Tags: android, events, timeout, focus, android-anr-dialog

In my Android application I am getting a very strange crash randomly. When I open the application I am fetching data from server on splash screen. When the application land on home page suddenly whole application is closed and here is what gets printed in the log:

```
ANR in com.test (com.test/.activities.SplashActivity)
    PID: 16020
    Reason: Input dispatching timed out (49abf6 com.test/com.test.activities.SplashActivity (server) is not responding. Waited 5004ms for FocusEvent(hasFocus=false))
Parent: com.test/.activities.SplashActivity
    Load: 29.87 / 30.79 / 30.77
    ----- Output from /proc/pressure/memory -----
    some avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=3115344
    full avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=1338179
    ----- End output from /proc/pressure/memory -----
```

Comment: Network call and I/O operation like heavy operation not in main thread. Use network lib retrofit and you can use coroutine.

Comment: I am already using retrofit. Can you help me with an example using coroutine? @Hemantvc

Comment: Find simple example of network call, https://camposha.info/android-examples/android-retrofit-coroutines/#gsc.tab=0
https://github.com/hemantvc/kotlin-retrofit/blob/main/app/src/main/java/org/hariom/kotlin_retrofit/NewsService.kt

Answer (score 7):

The cause of this exception is that UI thread is blocked and your application is not responding for more than 5 seconds.

Double check that the code fetching data from server is not executed on main thread. Also if you are using a braodcast receiver to do any logic that could take 10 seconds will lead to this issue.

Something else to check is the exception handling in the code fetching data from server.

You can take a look at the following page also:
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html#anr

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33211590)

Answer (score -1):

I encountered this issue when I was trying to make my foreground service wait for some duration. The fix was to use android.os.Handler. This will make the code inside the block run after `delay_in_millis` milliseconds and not make the entire service sleep (and then there was another error `App isn't responding`).

```
import android.os.Handler;

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // code to run after delay
    }
}, delay_in_millis);
```

Comment: This is not really related with the question. There could be a lot of things could cause ANR's and posting solutions to other ANR problems won't be really helpful.